# Chat app - Socket.IO/Angular/MongoDB - Chat and chat history not displayed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, socket.io, chat

I created a simple chat app and **the chat and chat history are not displayed**. The following are the codes. Please advise.

[The image of the chat app I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdYfQ.png)

**View (index.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="chatApp">

<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation/css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Chat</h1>
    <div ng-controller="ChatCtrl">
        <div id="chatWrap">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="msg in msgs">{{msg.text}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form ng-submit="sendMsg()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="msg.text" /> </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**AngularJS Controller (main.js)**

```
var app = angular.module('chatApp', []);
app.factory('socket', function () {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    return socket;
});
app.controller('ChatCtrl', function ($scope, socket) {
    $scope.msgs = [];
    $scope.sendMsg = function () {
        socket.emit('send msg', $scope.msg.text);
        $scope.msg.text = '';
    };
    socket.on('get old messages', function (docsCallback) {

        console.log(docsCallback);
        $scope.msgs.push(docsCallback);
        $scope.$digest();
    });
    socket.on('get msg', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.msgs.push(data);
        $scope.$digest();
    });
});
```

**Server (app.js)**

```
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , mongoose = require('mongoose');
server.listen(3000);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chatAppDB', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log('connected');
});
var msgSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String
    , time: {
        type: Date
        , default: Date.now
    }
});
var Chat = mongoose.model("Messages", msgSchema);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    'extended': 'true'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
}));
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('working');
    Chat.find({}, function (err, docsCallback) {
        console.log(docsCallback);
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Sending old messages');
        socket.emit('get old messages', docsCallback);

    });
    socket.on('send msg', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var newMsg = new Chat({
            text: data
        });
        newMsg.save(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else io.sockets.emit('get msg', data);
        });
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a directive), which will force a $digest().

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

create another array `allMsgs` which stores all the messages, and define `msgs` as an object type `{}` not an `array []`. And print all the messages from `allMsgs` array.

```
app.controller('ChatCtrl', function ($scope, socket) {
    $scope.msgs = {};
    $scope.sendMsg = function () {
        socket.emit('send msg', $scope.msg.text);
        $scope.msg.text = '';
    };
    socket.on('get old messages', function (docsCallback) {

        console.log(docsCallback);
        $scope.allMsgs = docsCallback;
        $scope.$digest();
    });
    socket.on('get msg', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.allMsgs =data;
        $scope.$digest();
    });
});
```

In your HTML template, replace `msgs` with `allMsgs`

```
    <div id="chatWrap">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="msg in allMsgs">{{msg.text}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: The problem still persists. The chats are still not displayed on the chat app. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: can you see the messages in the console, when you do `console.log`?

Comment: Yes, I can see the messages of both of the sockets (to simulate chat) in the consoles of both of the sockets when I do console.log. 

This is the [screenshot of one of the consoles](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46YlA7HVz4-Vmw2anE3elNWRnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: which is the line 19 according to the screenshot?Also, According to the screenshot, there is no `text` field in the `data` . Can you try `{{msg}}` instead of `{{msg.text}}` in your HTML template, and see if that works.

Comment: Line 19 are the new messages ("Hello world" and "Testing"). Those above the line 19 are the messages from the MongoDB ("Hello, how are you", etc.). This is what happened after I tried {{msg}}:- [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46YlA7HVz4-Y3RqQ0pad3M5QTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi. The messages can finally be displayed. However, there is still problem with it. The messages disappear after I enter a message and they show up after I refresh the page. I recorded [a video of it] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46YlA7HVz4-WU1EbFFCSXJMcXM/view?usp=sharing). By the way, I followed instruction of the AngularJS debugger and fixed [a minor bug](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=msg%20in%20allMsgs&p1=string:t&p2=t).

Comment: I saw the video, i think it is because of the line `$scope.allMsgs = [];` .Try removing that line. I will edit my answer, you can check.

Comment: Hi. It is still the same (like that in the video) after removing the "$scope.allMsgs = []".

Comment: i might need more code to understand the actual problem then, i could help this much with what is given above. Also, while getting all the data using `socket.on('get msg', function (data)` why are you retrieving all the message at once, why not just the new message instead. after retrieving new message you can push it to the array `allMsgs`.

Comment: Hi Ravi. I really need your help on fixing the codes. I get what your last sentence mean and tried changing the codes accordingly but I am too dumb to be able to make them right. Here are the codes:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46YlA7HVz4-TjF6d3VxUlk5T2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I will look into the code,and try to help you as much as i can.